# Remove ''List of Figures'' title

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I remove the title of my list of figures?
I am able to do it for the table of contents but not for the list of tables or figures.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Have you tried `\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{}`? The answer is dependent on the used documentclass, so please try to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @Johannes_B, it is an article. It works for me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @Johannes_B, because I'm using another title with a different layout. Before your help, I had 'List of figures' printed twice.

Answer (score 4):

Kind of late but I stumbled on to this to remove list of table name:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
        \@starttoc{lot}%
}
\makeatother
```

For list of figures, replace  listoftables with listoffigures and
\@starttoc{lot}% 
with 
\@starttoc{lof}%

Comment: So you mean `\listofffigures` -> lof and `\listoftables` -> lot ? I do not understand your replace comment... now its `\listoffigures` -> lot !